# Python calls the same function in a loop, and uses the return value of the last call as the parameter of this call

Tags: python

This is kmeans I wrote. I want to call this function cyclically to repeatedly calculate the distance to the center point and enter the return as parameter
the first input is `(b[0,:],b[1,:])`

```
def DIV(point1,point2):   
    plt.figure()
    c = []
    d = []
    for i in range(1000):
        dist1 = np.linalg.norm(Z[i] - point1)
        dist2 = np.linalg.norm(Z[i] - point2)
        if dist1 > dist2:
            c.append(Z[i])
        else:
            d.append(Z[i])
    C = np.array(c)
    D = np.array(d)
    plt.scatter(C[:,0],C[:,1],s=16.,color='green')
    plt.scatter(D[:,0],D[:,1],s=16.,color='yellow')

    center1 = C.mean(axis=0)
    center2 = D.mean(axis=0)
    plt.scatter(center1[0],center1[1],marker ='x',s=16.,color='red')
    plt.scatter(center2[0],center2[1],marker ='x',s=16.,color='red')
    return center1,center2
```

Comment: Assuming 'cyclically' means 'recursively', what do you expect to be your base condition?  None of your context or implementation will matter in this case, so you can edit it out to be a function that returns something =)

Comment: @Cireo I want to call this function in a loop, let its return as parameter, until the return does not change, or manually limit the number of repetitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function and background don't matter much, sounds like you are basically trying to do a "fixed point" function based on your response to my comment:

```
def fix(func, initial, max_iter):
    prev = func(initial)
    iteration = 1
    while True:
        curr = func(prev)
        if curr == prev or iteration > max_iter:
            break
        prev = curr
        iteration += 1
    return curr
```

For your specific case, you could then write

```
div = lambda (a, b): DIV(a, b)
result = fix(div, (b[0,:],b[1,:]), max_iter=1000)
```

if you wanted to use the same logic inline, instead of using more generic logic, you could write

```
prev = DIV(b[0,:],b[1,:])
iteration = 1
while True:
    curr = DIV(*prev)
    if curr == prev or iteration > 1000:
        break
    prev = curr
    iteration += 1
result = curr
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Does the inline example make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I used very cumbersome loops and functions to control its iteration

```
    def paste(head, start=0, stop=0, step=1, sep=''):
        return [f'{head}{sep}{i}' for i in range(start, stop, step)]
   def loop(n):
        k = paste('a', 0, n)
        k[0],k[1] = DIV(b[0,:],b[1,:])
        for i in range(0,n,2):
            k[i],k[i+1] = DIV(k[i],k[i+1])
            for j in range(2,n,2):            
                k[j],k[j+1] = DIV(k[i],k[i+1])

    loop(6)
```